# XmlValueDisconnectedException when saving information in excel with Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to overwrite an excel file with my java code:

```
List <Tuple> copy = 
    selectFrom(delivery_plan).
    list();
int row = 2;
int lastrow2 = main.DeliveredData.getLastRowNum(2);
for(int row2=2; row2<= lastrow2; row2++){
    main.DeliveredData.clearCell(2,row2,1);
    main.DeliveredData.clearCell(2,row2,2);
    main.DeliveredData.clearCell(2,row2,3);
    main.DeliveredData.clearCell(2,row2,4);
    main.DeliveredData.clearCell(2,row2,5);
    main.DeliveredData.clearCell(2,row2,6);

};
//iterating through all entries and saving into our excel sheet
for(Tuple tup : copy){
    main.DeliveredData.setCellValue(tup.get(delivery_plan.data),2,row,1);
    main.DeliveredData.setCellValue(tup.get(delivery_plan.product),2,row,2);
    main.DeliveredData.setCellValue(tup.get(delivery_plan.original_committed_qty),2,row,3);
    main.DeliveredData.setCellValue(tup.get(delivery_plan.updated_committe),2,row,4);
    main.DeliveredData.setCellValue(tup.get(delivery_plan.min_qty),2,row,5);
    main.DeliveredData.setCellValue(tup.get(delivery_plan.max_qty),2,row,6);
    row ++;
};

main.DeliveredData.writeFile();
```

However, when my code is executed I get the following error message:

org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you are not giving enough information to reproduce your problem... your code is perfectly fine and shouldn't give that error at all.

Comment: Make sure to close the excel file before running the code. Also: Do you run an experiment with parallel runs (such as Monte Carlo)?